# Problem with updating a colum value in database

Tags: database, field, odoo-12

I need to update a field in res partner table when validating an invoice.
I tried this code but nothing is done in database.can you help me please

```
partner.actual_quota = self.partner_id.credit_quota - invoices + payments
self.env['res.partner'].update(actual_quota)
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? what is invoices + payments?  and what do you mean by validation ? validate invoice is making it's state to open and create account moves?

Comment: I solved that. payments and invoices are variables containing the sum of invoices and payments. Thank you